# Can I disable dead keys for a single application?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, kde, keyboard, dead-keys

I am unable to properly use dead key characters ( ' " ^ ) on (k)ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 in arduino (a processing based application, at least version 0022 and 1.0).

Can I disable dead keys for specific application or application window, or does anybody know another work around?

'Dead keys' is the mechanism used to enter charactes like á ë ' ^, by first striking the accent-like key, then followed by a second key. The result is a combined character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out a work around. In KDE the keyboard configuration can be set in:

- System Settings
- Keyboard Settings
- Layout
- Select 'Show indicator'
- Select 'Per window'
- Add
- Select a variant without 'dead keys', eg. "English (US, with Euro on 5)"

After applying these settings, I select the window for input focus and I click the indicator in the system tray when I want to switch the keyboard configuration.
The keyboard setting needs only be set once per window and is rememberd over program restarts.